# Incompatible types in assignment - C

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of strings, but my compiler keeps saying I have imcompatible types in my assignment.

Below is the code in question.

```
for(i = 0; i < 499; i++) {
        max = 0;
        for(j = 1; j < 500; j++) {
            if(strncmp(user_id[max], user_id[j], 9) > 0) {
                printf("max = %s,    j = %s\n", user_id[max], user_id[j]);
                temp = user_id[j];
                user_id[j] = user_id[max];
                user_id[max] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

The following two lines throw the error:

```
 user_id[j] = user_id[max];
 user_id[max] = temp;
```

Why is it that I am receiving this error?

EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to include this before.

```
char user_id[500][9]; 
char* temp; 
i j and max are int. 

rover-208-149:prog3 kubiej21$ gcc --ansi --pedantic -o prog3 prog3.c 
prog3.c: In function ‘main’: 
prog3.c:46: error: incompatible types in assignment 
prog3.c:47: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

Comment: Impossible to say, because your code snippet doesn't include the definitions of `user_id` or `temp`, nor have you posted the exact error message.

Comment: Where are the definitions of `i`, `j`, `max`, `user_id`, `temp`, etc? What is the actual error message?

Comment: Please tell us what types are your user_id array and temp variable. If your compiler tell you it is incompatible types, that means they does not match.

Comment: Well, what are the types of `temp` and `user_id`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include this before.

char user_id[500][9];
char* temp;
i j and max are int.

rover-208-149:prog3 kubiej21$ gcc --ansi --pedantic -o prog3 prog3.c
prog3.c: In function ‘main’:
prog3.c:46: error: incompatible types in assignment
prog3.c:47: error: incompatible types in assignment

Comment: Edit that information into the question so we can see it without having to look through comments, please.

Comment: is your temo a `char temp[9]`?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not assignable in C.  So the following is not valid:

```
char user_id[500][9];

user_id[23] = user_id[42];  // Error: trying to assign array
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps `memcpy` is what you need?

```
memcpy(user_id[23], user_id[42], sizeof(user_id[23]));
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll give it a shot. Just for reference, I'm trying to create a selection sort.